# Is it possible to define directory path in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, path, shortcut

I'm using visual studio to create a game using the SDL library. I've also created my own static library that my game relies on. (It's the basic engine that sets up sdl, maps, ect.). Now when I include one of the files from my custom library, I have to type it like this:

`#include <SDL_Game_Engine/Files/whatever.h>`

Obviously that can be a bit tedious in typing all that.
So what I'm wondering is if there's a way in properties that will allow me to type

`#include <Engine/whatever.h>`

(Basically take the whole path to the file and make a shortcut for it).

I know it's a long shot but it would be awesome if there is a way. I don't like to have my include directory to include up to the files directory that way I know that the file I'm using is in my SDL_Game_Engine library. Is this even possible (with my luck there's no way lol) but any suggestions would be awesome. Thanks guys!

PS. Using Visual Studio 2015

Comment: you can add an existing project as dependency, or use linker on the property project i guess :).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the SDL library is but..perhaps you can place things in an app.config and then assign a variables to your path;
String filePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["YourFilePathKeyInAppConfig"];
then use it in code:
someGameVarFile = filePath; //psuedo code